# Create a border around UIImageView using 8 images

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I have 8 images I made, 4 images for each of the corners, and 4 images for each of the sides of `UIImageView`. Now, how on Earth do I make them 'come around' the `view` so they form a nice-looking, stretchable border, something like this (the white line is the border I try to implement):
[image]

Any ideas on how do you implement a border of a `view` based on 8 preset images?

**EDIT:** I don't want to *draw* the border, I want to use my 8 images!

Comment: and what is the red area? is your imageView frame just the photo we see or does it contains the red area too?

Comment: @meronix its the red area, just couldn't resize the image properly, but it has nothing to do with this question

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not really what you are asking for but this is the solution closest to what you are trying to do.

You should take your 8 images and combine them into one single image and then make a resizable image out of that using [`resizableImageWithCapInsets:resizingMode:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:).

The first arguments lets you specify the top, left, bottom and right inset (i.e. the sizes of your images).

[image]

The second argument determines if the areas are stretched or tiled.

Stretched
[image: Stretched border]

Tiled
[image: Tiled border]

So to use it you would do something similar to

```
UIImage *myFullImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nameOfTheCombinedImage"];
UIImage *resizableImage = 
[myFullImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeTile];
```

(stretched vs tiles images "borrowed" from [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/))

Comment: Sounds nice. Any example on this?

Comment: David, would you mind relicensing your answer under the MIT License?   The Creative Commons license of StackOverflow is tricky to reuse.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza I wasn't fully aware of the problem but as far as I'm concerned you are free to do whatever you want with the answers. I've also updated my profile so that the MIT license applies to all my answers.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza Just be aware that some images in some answers are not mine to change the license of. In this example the first image is mine and free for you to use however you want, but the other two are from [css3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/) (as mentioned in the answer) and may have other licenses that apply to those images.