# Hard time understanding the resizableImageWithCapInsets

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a UIButton and I am trying to set a resizable image as background. The image is 25X25 points in size. I use the following code to set the image.

```
UIImage *backgroundImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"barbutton_normal"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 2, 3, 2)];

    [self setBackgroundImage:backgroundImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,10, 10, 10)];

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

But the button appears like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Also how can I make the top and bottom portion of the button a little bigger so that it does not look crammed up with the text.

Comment: What should it look like?

Comment: Do my illustrations in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14648532/608157) help you?

Comment: Thanks David! But I am still confused as what is top, left, right and bottom. What does it represent?

Comment: @johndoe they represent the distance from the top, left, right and bottom of your image that should not be stretched (look at the first image in my other answer again). You pass them as the edge insets `UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, left, bottom, right)`